# Adding JavaScript click event to my htmlDropDownList

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC and HTML helpers.

I have the need that when a User clicks on a drop-down a JavaScript function is called.

There are many drop-downs and my HTML for that line is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("A" + item.FeatureId, Model.FeatureOptions,
      new Dictionary<string, object> { { "onchange", "javascript:featureOptionChanged(itemId, optionId);" } })

function featureOptionChanged(itemId featureId) {
    alert(featureId);
}
```

Even though my JavaScript *is* defined I get an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: featureOptionChanged is not defined

Comment: try changing onclick with onchange event.

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip.I just realised that myself but this still does not work :(

Comment: make sure that your javascript function is loaded properly. Here Error Clearly indicates that somehow it is not able to load that javascript function and thats why it is not able to find when on change event is fired.

Comment: @AshokRathodHi, thanks for taking an interest. That was my conclusion as well.  I had wrapped my function in '$(document).ready(function() {}' but still the same error

Comment: you need a comma after itemId in your argument list